# IE 11 not play OGG file in Audio Tag

Tags: html, audio

i want to play ogg file in browser. Google Chrome play the file but IE11 and Firefox not play the file.

IE11 display "Invalid Source" when i try to play the file.

[image]

```
<audio controls autoplay><source  src='MySRC' type="audio/ogg" /></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 [doesn't support the ogg](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ogg-vorbis) file format. Try M4A instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one
[Read the following for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio)
 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio